# Thresholding image in OpenCV for a range of max and min values

Tags: opencv

I like to threshold an image within a range max and min value and fill the rest with 255 for those pixel values out of that range. I can't find such threshold in OpenCV document [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/threshold/threshold.html#truncate).
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic:

```
threshold(src, dst, threshold value, max value, threshold type);
```

where

```
src_gray: Our input image
dst: Destination (output) image
threshold_value: The thresh value with respect to which the thresholding operation is made
max_BINARY_value: The value used with the Binary thresholding operations (to set the chosen pixels)
threshold_type: One of the 5 thresholding operations.
```

so for example,

```
threshold(image, fImage, 125, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
```

means every value below 125, will be set to zero, and above 125 to the value of 255.

If what you are looking for is to have a particular range, for instance 50 to 150, I would recommend you do a for loop, and check and edit the pixels yourself. It is very simple. Take a look at this c++ code of mine:

```
for (int i=0; i< image.rows; i++)
    { 
        for (int j=0; j< image.cols; j++)
        {
            int editValue=image.at<uchar>(i,j);

            if((editValue>50)&&(editValue<150)) //check whether value is within range.
            {
                image.at<uchar>(i,j)=255;
            }
            else
            {
                image.at<uchar>(i,j)=0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope I solved your problem. Cheers(: Do comment if you need more help.

Answer (score 16):

```
inRange(src, lowerBound, upperBound, dst);
bitwise_not(src, src);
```

Comment: FYI for other readers: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange

Comment: This answer would help people way more if you just added some comment to it to explain what each line does.

Comment: This may be late, but what exactly does the `bitwise_not` accomplish in this case? I tried just the first line in Python, and it seemed to do the job without a need for anything else.

Comment: @MLavrentyev inRange sets the values within the bounds to 255, and 0 otherwise. The question seems to ask for the reverse, hence the bitwise_not operation.